# optional regex patten in td-agent

Tags: ruby, regex, fluentd

I have two different format of logs line, you can make test using this [site](http://rubular.com/)

I need to keep optional **client section** in below line, if it is present it conclude otherwise it ignore

```
\[(?<date>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<level>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<pid-tid>[^\]]*)\] (\[(?<client>[^\]]*)\]) (?<message>[^\]]*)
```

**Log Lines - without client**

[Mon Jan 18 21:55:58.239970 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2769:tid 140041068427008] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: xx.xxx.xx.xx

**Log Lines - with client**

[Mon Jan 18 21:55:58.239970 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2769:tid 140041068427008] [client xx.xxx.x.xx:10723] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: xx.xxx.xx.xx

I have tried like (.*?clientsection) -> 0 or more matches

```
\[(?<date>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<level>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<pid-tid>[^\]]*)\] (.*?(\[(?<client>[^\]]*)\])) (?<message>[^\]]*)
```

but it does not work

Comment: Check [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/NgdcGte2rN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second expression,  `(.*?(\[(?<client>[^\]]*)\]))` part matches an obligatory space, and then captures any 0+ chars, as few as possible, then captures 0+ chars other than `]` into "client"  group and then matches `]` placing it inside the numbered capture group. If the client part is missing in the text, your expression will attempt to match the first space, then a `[...]` substring, and then again a space.

If you want to fix the regex, you need to *make the "client" group optional* and make sure the adjoining context is also made optional.

Replace the  `(.*?(\[(?<client>[^\]]*)\]))` with `(?: \[(?<client>[^\]]*)\])?`. Here, `(?:...)?` is an optional non-capturing group that will create no subgroup (no capture), and will match 1 or 0 occurrences of its pattern, only if all that sequence is present.

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/NgdcGte2rN) (`\n` is added to the negated character classes since a multiline string is used for testing).